# How to reference a parent but attach a tag to it in sass?

Tags: css, sass

If I have this

```
.A {

}
input.A {

}
```

how can I use sass to factor out the parent .A? I tried

```
.A {

  input.& {

  } 
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: In what way did it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sass always seems to have a problem when appending the parent selector at the end. It doesn't have any problems when the parent selector is added at the start or in the middle.

One possible solution would be to use the [`@at-root` directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root). The `@at-root` directive tells compiler to move the selector to the root level (instead of being an inner nested block) and then appending the parent selector through [selector interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) produces the expected output.

```css
.A {
  @at-root input#{&} {
    property: value;
  } 
}
```

(*Using just selector interpolation without `@at-root` directive would end up producing `.A input.A`.*)